# Retorna valor incorrecto JAVA

Tags: java, get

Os comento mi duda, antemano decir que estoy empezando con Java y estoy practicando con los métodos, vengo de otro lenguaje también orientado a objetos pero igualmente a muy bajo nivel.

Mi duda o fallo es el siguiente, estoy, a modo de afición, creando una aplicación que me sirva para autogenerar fichas de personajes para un juego de rol en concreto, esto tiene que ver varias tiradas aleatorias de dados, pues bien, en una de las clases (perdón si me equivoco en los términos) he diseñado una serie de consultas con condicionales "if" anidados para ir resolviendo el tipo de personaje que vas a querer jugar, previamente recibes los parámetros y creo un array, buen en este caso dos, para ordenar de mayor a menos los valores y repartirlos según interese mas al resultado final del pj. Durante todo el método SETTER, los valores se gestionan correctamente, pero en cada uno de los métodos GETTER no consigo que me retorne el valor correcto y simplemente me retorna un int variable = 0;

Os detallo el código de la clase en cuestión

```
public class Profesion {

private int fue, con, des, pod, car, tam, inte;
private String prof;

public Profesion() {

}

public int getFue() {
    return fue;
}

public int getCon() {
    return con;
}

public int getDes() {
    return des;
}

public int getPod() {
    return pod;
}

public int getCar() {
    return car;
}

public int getTam() {
    return tam;
}

public int getInte() {
    return inte;
}

public void setProf(int carTemp1, int carTemp2, int carTemp3, int carTemp4, int carTemp5,
    int carTemp6, int carTemp7) {

    int [] orden3d6 = {carTemp1, carTemp2, carTemp3, carTemp4, carTemp5};
    int [] orden2d6 = {carTemp6, carTemp7};

    Arrays.sort(orden3d6);
    Arrays.sort(orden2d6);

    prof = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Cuál Profesión tendra el personaje?",
            "Example1", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, new Object[] { "Adiestrador de animales", 
                    "Agente", "Alquimista", "Artesano", "Artista","Cazador", "Chaman", "Cortesana", 
                    "Cortesana", "Cortesano(burgués)", "Erudito", "Explorador", "Funcionario", "Granjero",
                    "Guerrero", "Hechicero", "Ladrón", "Marinero", "Médico", "Mercader", "Minero",
                    "Místico", "Pastor", "Pescador"}, "Guerrero");

    if (prof.equals("Adiestrador de animales")) {
        String resp1 = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Que tipo de Adiestrador?", "Example1", 
            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,null, new Object[] {"Luchador", "Instructor"}, "Instructor");
            if (resp1.equals("Luchador")) {
                fue = orden3d6[3];  
                con = orden3d6[1];
                des = orden3d6[0];
                pod = orden3d6[4];      
                car = orden3d6[2];      
                tam = orden2d6[0];
                inte = orden2d6[1];
            }else if(resp1.equals("Instructor")) {
                fue = orden3d6[0];
                con = orden3d6[1];
                des = orden3d6[2];
                pod = orden3d6[4];      
                car = orden3d6[3];      
                tam = orden2d6[0];
                inte = orden2d6[1];
            }else {
                System.out.println ("Respuesta no válida");
            }


        }

        if (prof.equals("Guerrero")) {
            String resp1 = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Que tipo de guerrero?", "Example1", 
                    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,null, new Object[] {"Tanque", "Ágil", "Equilibrado"}, "Equilibrado");
            if (resp1.equals("Equilibrado")) {
                fue = orden3d6[4];
                con = orden3d6[3];
                des = orden3d6[2];
                pod = orden3d6[0];      
                car = orden3d6[1];      
                tam = orden2d6[1];
                inte = orden2d6[0];
            }else if(resp1.equals("Ágil")) {
                fue = orden3d6[2];
                con = orden3d6[3];
                des = orden3d6[4];
                pod = orden3d6[0];      
                car = orden3d6[1];      
                tam = orden2d6[0];
                inte = orden2d6[1];
            }else if(resp1.equals("Tanque")) {
                fue = orden3d6[2];
                con = orden3d6[4];
                des = orden3d6[3];
                pod = orden3d6[0];      
                car = orden3d6[1];      
                tam = orden2d6[1];
                inte = orden2d6[0];
            }else {
                System.out.println ("Respuesta no válida");
            }
        }


    }

}
```

Añado la clase main:

```
package PJ;
```

public class Crear_PJ {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Caracteristicas car1 = new Caracteristicas();
    Caracteristicas car2 = new Caracteristicas();
    Caracteristicas car3 = new Caracteristicas();
    Caracteristicas car4 = new Caracteristicas();
    Caracteristicas car5 = new Caracteristicas();
    Caracteristicas car6 = new Caracteristicas();
    Caracteristicas car7 = new Caracteristicas();

    Atributos pA  = new Atributos(); 
    Atributos mD = new Atributos();

    Profesion orden = new Profesion();
    Profesion fue = new Profesion();
    Profesion con = new Profesion();
    Profesion des = new Profesion();
    Profesion pod = new Profesion();
    Profesion car = new Profesion();
    Profesion tam = new Profesion();
    Profesion inte = new Profesion();


    car1.setCAR_3d6();
    car2.setCAR_3d6();
    car3.setCAR_3d6();
    car4.setCAR_3d6();
    car5.setCAR_3d6();
    car6.setCAR_2d6();
    car7.setCAR_2d6();

    int carTemp1 = car1.getCAR_3d6();
    int carTemp2 = car2.getCAR_3d6();
    int carTemp3 = car3.getCAR_3d6();
    int carTemp4 = car4.getCAR_3d6();
    int carTemp5 = car5.getCAR_3d6();
    int carTemp6 = car6.getCAR_2d6();
    int carTemp7 = car7.getCAR_2d6();


    orden.setProf(carTemp1, carTemp2, carTemp3, carTemp4, carTemp5, carTemp6, carTemp7);


    int fuE = fue.getFue();
    int coN = con.getCon();
    int deS = des.getDes();
    int poD = pod.getPod();
    int caR = car.getCar();
    int taM = tam.getTam();
    int inTe = inte.getInte();

    mD.setMD(fuE, taM);
    pA.setPA(deS, inTe);


    System.out.println("La FUE es " + fuE);
    System.out.println("La CON es " + coN);
    System.out.println("El TAM es " + taM);
    System.out.println("El DES es " + deS);
    System.out.println("El INT es " + inTe);
    System.out.println("El POD es " + poD);
    System.out.println("El CAR es " + caR);
    System.out.println("Los Puntos de Acción son " + pA.getPA());
    System.out.println("El modificaro de daño es " + mD.getMD());
}
```

}

Y la clase Atributos :

```
package PJ;
```

public class Atributos {

```
private int pA;
private int ac;
private int mD;
private String daño;

public Atributos() {
    ac = 0;
    daño = "";
}

public int getPA() {
    return ac;
}

public String getMD() {
    return daño;
}


public void setPA(int des, int inte ) {

    pA = des + inte;
    if (pA<13) {
        ac = 1;
    }else if (pA>12 && pA<25) {
        ac = 2;
    }else if (pA>25 && pA<37) {
        ac = 3;
    }else if (pA>36 && pA<49) {
        ac = 4;
    }else if (pA>49) {
        ac = 5;
    }else ac = 0;


}


public void setMD(int fue, int tam) {

    mD = fue + tam;

    if (mD<6) {
        daño = "-1d8";
    }else if (mD>7 && mD<11) {
        daño = "-1d6";
    }else if (mD>7 && mD<11) {
        daño = "-1d6";
    }else if (mD>10 && mD<16) {
        daño = "-1d4";
    }else if (mD>15 && mD<21) {
        daño = "-1d2";
    }else if (mD>20 && mD<26) {
        daño = "0";
    }else if (mD>25 && mD<31) {
        daño = "+1d2";
    }else if (mD>30 && mD<36) {
        daño = "+1d4";
    }else if (mD>35 && mD<41) {
        daño = "+1d6";
    }else if (mD>40 && mD<46) {
        daño = "+1d8";
    }else if (mD>45 && mD<51) {
        daño = "+1d10";
    }else if (mD>50 && mD<61) {
        daño = "+1d12";
    }else if (mD>70 && mD<81) {
        daño = "+2d6";
    }else if (mD>80 && mD<91) {
        daño = "+2d8";
    }else if (mD>90 && mD<101) {
        daño = "+1d10+1d8";
    }else if (mD>100 && mD<111) {
        daño = "+2d10";
    }else if (mD>110 && mD<121) {
        daño = "+2d10+1d2";
    }else if (mD>120 && mD<131) {
        daño = "+2d10+1d4";
    }else daño = "Consulta tabla pag 13";



}
```

}

Añado la tirada inicial de dados:

```
package PJ;
```

class Caracteristicas {

```
private double dado3d6_1, dado3d6_2, dado3d6_3;
private int valor;

public Caracteristicas(){valor = 0;}

public int getCAR_3d6() {return valor;}

public int getCAR_2d6() {return valor;}

public void setCAR_3d6() {

    do {
        dado3d6_1=Math.random()*6;
    } while (dado3d6_1 < 1);

    do {
        dado3d6_2=Math.random()*6;
    } while (dado3d6_2 < 1);

    do {
        dado3d6_3=Math.random()*6;
    } while (dado3d6_3 < 1);

    valor = (int)(dado3d6_1+dado3d6_2+dado3d6_3);

}

public void setCAR_2d6() {

    do {
        dado3d6_1=Math.random()*6;
    } while (dado3d6_1 < 1);

    do {
        dado3d6_2=Math.random()*6;
    } while (dado3d6_2 < 1);

    valor = (int)(dado3d6_1+dado3d6_2+6);
}
```

}

Comment: donde utilizas los get ? podrias mostrarnos ese codigo ?

Comment: Si claro!! Edito el mensaje principal, el valor viaja bien desde las otras clases incluso dentro del método SET, el valor se mantiene, el problema es en el método GET que hay ya me retorna un 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No te hace falta hacer esto

```
 Profesion orden = new Profesion();
    Profesion fue = new Profesion();
    Profesion con = new Profesion();
    Profesion des = new Profesion();
    Profesion pod = new Profesion();
    Profesion car = new Profesion();
    Profesion tam = new Profesion();
    Profesion inte = new Profesion();
```

Estas generando una instancia distinta cada vez que llamas a

```
Profesion x = new Profesion();
```

Para eso instancia una sola vez y usa los setters y getters de esa clase porejemplo

```
Profesion profesion = new Profesion();
```

Seteando valores

```
profesion.setFue(20);
```

obteniendolos

```
profesion.getFue();
```

Lo mismo que con esto

```
Caracteristicas car1 = new Caracteristicas();
    Caracteristicas car2 = new Caracteristicas();
    Caracteristicas car3 = new Caracteristicas();
    Caracteristicas car4 = new Caracteristicas();
    Caracteristicas car5 = new Caracteristicas();
    Caracteristicas car6 = new Caracteristicas();
    Caracteristicas car7 = new Caracteristicas();
```

instancialo igual que profesion , una sola vez

```
 Caracteristicas car = new Caracteristicas();
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta Gastón, pero en mi caso no seteo de valor en valor, si no que los mando los 7 valores para dentro convertirlo en dos arrays y ordenarlos, y distribuirlos según convenga. Añado también la clase que me falto donde se tiran los dados para establecer los valores.

Comment: Por el tema de las instancias, si que es verdad, lo he correigo e instanciado una sola vez

Comment: Solucionado, gracias por los aportes, era efectivamente un fallo de instanciamiento